# 2 different ways of writing javafx program : Where are they used?

Tags: javafx

I have seen online two different ways of writing JAvafx code. I'm confused about where are they applicable. I couldn't find a good example to have a proper explanation. So If anyone of you could help understand these ways, it would be a great help.

#### Way 1:

We code javafx with Java language which has an fxml, one controller and one main class extending Application.This way(According to me) is used to develop a desktop application as I've created many application using the same way. As shown below

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication10 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

#### Way 2:

For this way writing the code I couldn't find a good example. Hence I'm confused where I can use it. Not sure whether this is even a way or not. Refer to the link http://fxexperience.com/2009/06/example-3d-pie/

The code is as follows

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Alert;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart3D;

Stage {
    scene: Scene {
        height: 400
        width: 500
        content: PieChart3D {
            title: "Sample Pie"
            startAngle: 0
            data: [
                PieChart.Data { label: "Apples" value: 34 },
                PieChart.Data { label: "Oranges" value: 27 },
                PieChart.Data { label: "Bananas" value: 16 },
                PieChart.Data { label: "Grapes" value: 50 },
                PieChart.Data { label: "Cherries" value: 6 },
                PieChart.Data { label: "Strawberries" value: 5 },
                PieChart.Data { label: "Raspberries" value: 7 }
            ]
        }
    }
}

PieChart.Data { 
    label: "Apples"
    value: 34 action:function(){Alert.inform("Clicked on Apples")} 
}
```

The second way I'm not sure how it can be used. If anyone could help me understand it or give an example, would be great.

Comment: Is that javafx ***script***??? Use FXML instead...

Comment: People tend to use FXML or Java when working with JavaFX. JavaFX Script never really caught on. I can't even find any documentation for JavaFX Script in the Java 8 documentation anymore...

Comment: JavaFX Script *only* works for versions prior to JavaFX 2.0. It is no longer used. (Note that your link is from nearly 7 years ago.) Use either the Java-based way in your first example, or [FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Comment: That clears my doubt. Thank you all for your comments. One more questions. Was the javafx script used to create web pages?